# Why do two transactions making a read lock result in a DEADLOCK exception?

Tags: mysql, transaction, deadlock, mysql-5.7, concurrency

Let's assume a scenario that flows as follows:

1. Transaction #1 makes this query:

   ```
   SELECT v.id, v.name
   FROM versions_history as vh
   INNER JOIN versions as v
   ON vh.version_id = v.id
   WHERE vh.project_id = ?
   ORDER BY vh.id
   DESC
   FOR UPDATE
   ```
2. Transaction #2 makes the same query. At this point, transaction #2 state is "LOCK WAIT", since it is waiting for transaction #1 to release lock.
3. Transaction #1 makes this query:

   ```
   INSERT INTO versions_history SET ?
   ```
4. DEADLOCK Exception

   > "\n\tSELECT v.id, v.name\n\tFROM versions_history as vh\n\tINNER JOIN versions as v\n\tON vh.version_id = v.id\n\tWHERE vh.project_id = '1'\n\tORDER BY vh.id\n\tDESC\n\tFOR UPDATE\n\t - Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

This is the explanation of a deadlock from the MySQL documentation:

> A deadlock is a situation where different transactions are unable to proceed because each holds a lock that the other needs. Because both transactions are waiting for a resource to become available, neither ever release the locks it holds.

I really don't understand what lock the transaction #2 holds that transaction #1 needs. Transaction #2 doesn't have any locks, it's only waiting for transaction #1 to release it's first lock.

### **Additional points**

Here is the information about the deadlock (generated with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`):

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-10-09 17:26:46 0x700007582000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 16799872, ACTIVE 5 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1402, OS thread handle 123145426083840, query id 599065 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Sending data
SELECT v.id, v.name
    FROM versions_history as vh
    INNER JOIN versions as v
    ON vh.version_id = v.id
    WHERE vh.project_id = '1'
    ORDER BY vh.id
    DESC
    FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 534168 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `skytracks_test`.`versions_history` trx id 16799872 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 8 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000007; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c0164; asc     < d;;
3: len 4; hex 00000006; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 16799871, ACTIVE 7 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
15 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 38 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1401, OS thread handle 123145425526784, query id 599070 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
INSERT INTO versions_history SET `project_id` = '1', `version_id` = 7
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 534168 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `skytracks_test`.`versions_history` trx id 16799871 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c0110; asc     <  ;;
3: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c011e; asc     <  ;;
3: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000003; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c012c; asc     < ,;;
3: len 4; hex 00000003; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000004; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c013a; asc     < :;;
3: len 4; hex 00000004; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000003; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 6 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000005; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c0148; asc     < H;;
3: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 7 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000006; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c0156; asc     < V;;
3: len 4; hex 00000005; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 8 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000007; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000001005878; asc     Xx;;
2: len 7; hex b50000013c0164; asc     < d;;
3: len 4; hex 00000006; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 534168 page no 3 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `skytracks_test`.`versions_history` trx id 16799871 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Comment: "for update" isn't a read lock. what is the PK of versions_history?

Comment: SELECT .. FOR UPDATE query assumes that the UPDATE query will be executed immediately after. But you execute INSERT... think about the logic of your code.

Comment: @danblack Yes it is (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: Show us the entire transaction, not just the statement that go taught.